# Detecting and displaying number of players detected using Kinect

Tags: wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I'm trying to display number of players detected by Kinect sensor using an WPF application. In addition to displaying number of player I have also coloured the pixels based on their distance from the Kinect. Original goal was to measure the distance of the pixels and display the distance but I would also like to display how many people are in the frame. Here is the code snippets that I'm using now.

PS I have borrowed the idea from [`THIS`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwJmsmLYjcU&index=4&list=PLolXZ_FSzSVVPXr5XQj00HQ5AuP3cT1Ui) tutorial and I'm using SDK 1.8 with XBOX 360 Kinect (1414)

```
private void _sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
        {
            if (depthFrame==null)
            {
                return;
            }
            byte[] pixels = GenerateColoredBytes(depthFrame);
            int stride = depthFrame.Width * 4;
            image.Source = BitmapSource.Create(depthFrame.Width, depthFrame.Height, 
            96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, pixels, stride);
        }
    }

private byte[] GenerateColoredBytes(DepthImageFrame depthFrame)
    {   
       //get the raw data from kinect with the depth for every pixel
        short[] rawDepthData = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
        depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(rawDepthData);
        /*
        Use depthFrame to create the image to display on screen
        depthFrame contains color information for all pixels in image
        */
        //Height * Width *4 (Red, Green, Blue, Empty byte)
        Byte[] pixels = new byte[depthFrame.Height * depthFrame.Width * 4];
        //Hardcoded loactions for Blue, Green, Red (BGR) index positions
        const int BlueIndex = 0;
        const int GreenIndex = 1;
        const int RedIndex = 2;
        //Looping through all distances and picking a RGB colour based on distance

        for (int depthIndex = 0, colorIndex = 0; 
            depthIndex < rawDepthData.Length && 
            colorIndex<pixels.Length; depthIndex++, colorIndex+=4)
        {
            //Getting player
            int player = rawDepthData[depthIndex] & DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmask;

            //Getting depth value
            int depth =rawDepthData[depthIndex]>>DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth;

            //.9M or 2.95'
            if (depth <=900 )
            {
                //Close distance
                pixels[colorIndex + BlueIndex] = 0;
                pixels[colorIndex + GreenIndex] = 0;
                pixels[colorIndex + RedIndex] = 255;
                //textBox.Text = "Close Object";
            }

            //.9M - 2M OR 2.95' - 6.56'
            else if (depth >900 && depth<2000)
            {
                //Bit further away
                pixels[colorIndex + BlueIndex] = 255;
                pixels[colorIndex + GreenIndex] = 0;
                pixels[colorIndex + RedIndex] = 0;
            }

            else if (depth > 2000)
            {
                //Far away
                pixels[colorIndex + BlueIndex] = 0;
                pixels[colorIndex + GreenIndex] = 255;
                pixels[colorIndex + RedIndex] = 0;
            }

            //Coloring all people in Gold
            if (player > 0)
            {
                pixels[colorIndex + BlueIndex] = Colors.Gold.B;
                pixels[colorIndex + GreenIndex] = Colors.Gold.G;
                pixels[colorIndex + RedIndex] = Colors.Gold.R;
                playersValue.Text = player.ToString();
            }
        }
        return pixels;
    }
```

Current goal is to--

- Detect total number of players detected and display them in a `textBox`
- Colour them according to the distance logic i.e `depth <=900 is red`.

With current code I can detect player and color them in Gold but as soon as a player is detected the `image` freezes and when the player is out of the frame the `image` unfreezes and acts normal. Is it because of the loop?
Ideas, guidance, recommendation and criticism all are welcome.

Thanks!

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get a static variable inside your form code

Then set this variable using your video frame routine (dont define it there).

And then update the textbox view, probaply in your _sensor_AllFramesReady
As the arrival of new frames runs in a different thread
I dont see all code maybe to update call textbox.show

the main loop looks a bit strange though, too complex.
basicly you use it to color every pixel in your image.
as the kinect360 has 320x240 pixels so that makes a depth array of size 76800
You might simply create 2 for next loops loops for X and Y and then inside this loop have a variable increase to pick the proper depth value.